# Css pseudo classes are changing select value when mouse leave on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, pseudo-class

I have interesting problem to solve.

Im using combination of pseudoclasses (exacly like here: `div[data-used="true"]:hover::after`) to change content of my `after` element, when `hover` like here:

```css
select{
  color: #9E9E9E;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  border-color: #BDBDBD;
  outline: none;
  margin: 4px 8px;
  height: 48px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  line-height: 21px;
}

select:hover{
  border-color: #03A9F4 !important;
  color: #03A9F4 !important;
  background: #fff !impotrant;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.36);
}

select:first-of-type{
  margin-left: 0;
}

div[data-used="true"]{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

div[data-used="true"]::after{
  content: "✓";
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 15px;
  height: 26px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 2px;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-indent: -9px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #8BC34A;
  font-weight: 600;
  left: -1px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

div[data-used="true"]:hover::after{
  content: "✖";
  text-indent: -11px;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #2196F3;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="req" data-used="true">
  <label>
    <div class="addad-step-box">
      <div class="addad-step">Rodzaj paliwa<sup>*</sup></div>
    </div>
  </label>
  <select id="xyz_paliwo">
    <option>-- wybierz --</option>
    <option>Benzyna</option>
    <option>Diesel</option>
    <option>Benzyna + LPG</option>
    <option>Benzyna + CNG</option>
    <option>Hybryda</option>
    <option>Elektryczny</option>
    <option>Wodór</option>
    <option>Etanol</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

As you can see, on Firefox, when you choose something, and then you click again on the list but **you don't click any new value** but **hover new value and then leave mouse out of select**, select is changing value...

I don't know why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is confusing because you appear to be using the terms pseudo-class and pseudo-element interchangeably (and you have both of these things in your CSS).

Comment: Is confusing, or is not... I thing it's not a point. Maybe this mix of css attributres it's not really good and it's possible to make it in easier way, but is one from possible solution to make it. I mean, it's not incorrect way to do this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What happen usually

In a normal situation (without all these CSS properties) with an opened `<select`>, when the mouse go over `<select>` items, they are considered in succession as *selected* (a blue background is showed).

If you click on the item, it keep this *selected* state. `<select`> is closed, JS events are triggered, and the `<select>` showed value is this *selected* item.
If you open again the `<select>`, the item is still in blue.

If you click away while the `<select`> is opened, the *selected* item is reset to the previous one.

## What happened here

The bug come from the crossing of two Firefox behaviors :

- When a `div::after` content change, the `div` (and his children) rendering is recalculated.
- A `<select>` always consider his *selected* item (the one with a blue background) as its current value.

Step by step :

1. You click on the `<select>`, it open the menu.
2. The mouse go over `<select>` items, which are considered in succession as  *selected*.
3. The mouse go out of the `<div>`, so :

   - `::after` content is changed
   - `<div>` content is recalculated
   - `<select>` is reset, so showed in its closed state
   - and... **the last element the mouse was over on is still *selected***

So the "visually closed" `<select>` show this last *selected* item as selected. No JS events are triggered.
But **It's not only a visual bug**. On Firefox, the `<select>` value (`elem.value`) is changed when the mouse go over its items.

**See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju5hz04a/6/)**

## How to fix it

It's a Firefox `<select>` behaviour, you can't do anything against that, except create your own select in Js.

To prevent the `<select>` to close when the mouse leave, remove :

```
div[data-used="true"]::after:hover{
    content: "✖";
}
```

Comment: "the `<select>` value is not changed" it changes for me

Comment: Yes, I know that it's only visual bug, but it's flustrating ;)

Comment: @SzymonPajka It's a browser bug, we can't do more :) Generally, avoid using pseudo-elements. Use sub-divs, and take a look at [a more organized CSS method, OOCSS](http://getbem.com/introduction/). Have you more questions ?

Comment: Edited. Thanks @Oriol to make me check. No JS events is triggered, but the `<select>` value change